# Anyone used Unified Write Filter (uwfmgr) and netsh together? I'm seeing some off things after running netsh and then rebooting

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10-iot-core, netsh, windows-10-iot-enterprise

I've have a Win10IoT Enterprise image I've built.
It is running with Unified Write Filter enabled on the system (C:) volume.

I have the following registry exclusions added to the system disk (the only protected volume) to allow changing IP addresses via netsh to persist and be saved through the filter.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces

When I boot the machine with the uwf filter ON I do the following actions....

1. Run netsh to set a static IP, Subnet, and gateway
2. Verify the commanbd worked with ipconfig
3. Check the NIC card GUI in Windows and also verify it looks good there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Everything at this point looks great.  I now reboot the machine (uwf filter still on).
When the machine reboots I check the IP address again via ipconfig and the NIC GUI to verify they are still good.

This is when things get odd.  The ipconfig looks fine, but in the GUI window the IP is listed as the last static IP address I set with the uwf filter OFF (192.168.0.20 in this example).  If I click the advanced settings there are two address listed under the IP Addresses, my expected 192.168.0.50 address as well as the old 192.168.0.20.

Some more info, the machine will respond to pings to 192.168.0.50 but will not respond to 192.168.0.20.  I'm guessing there is another registry setting somewhere that is getting reverted causing the GUI to not update correctly.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Post reboot images....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
But when I add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi to my exclusion list, it works

Comment: Good call.  That takes care of a soft boot and solves the issue described above.  If you simply drop power with UWF running the IP change doesn't persist at all (as if you never ran netsh).  I'm guessing the way UWF works there's no work around or solution for this.  I'm used to EWF RAM-Reg mode in Win 7 Embedded and would commit changes live if needed.